# angular $watch parent scope variable always fired

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent, watch, directive

**html**

```
<div data-select >
     <div data-set-tip tipit='selecting(tips)' ></div>
     <div data-show-tip headsup='selectingtips' ></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
directive.select= function(){
    return:{
        restrict:'A',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.selectingtips = '';
            $scope.selecting = function(tips){
                $scope.selectingtips = tips
            }
        }
    }
}

directive.setTip = function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            tipit:'&'
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.on('mousestop',function(){
                scope.tipit({tips:'some tips'})
            })
        }
    }

}

directive.showTip = function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            headsup:'&'
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            scope.$watch('headsup',function(){
                alert('changed')
            })
        }

    }
}
```

I want when mouse stop at setTip directive the parent directive variable selectingtips will be set to something, and the showTip directive always listen to the change of selectingtips,and when change happens alert change.

**problem**

when I refresh the page it will alert change immediately, and when I stop the mouse on setTip directive, nothing happens. 
note: the **selectingtips** did get changed when mouse stop at setTip directive.

what my doing wrong?

here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wJutkLW6yDwxABSK3a3M?p=preview)

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or fiddle please?

Comment: check out the plunker

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the `$watch` from firing on page load you'll need to compare the old and new values of model you're watching:

```js
scope.$watch('headsup',function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal != oldVal)
        alert('changed')
})
```

See the updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5kJSZtVA9a8o4tRdnPaT?p=preview

Comment: In order to prevent unwanted firing when loading data via ajax, I had to check oldVal against undefined as well (assumes that the data are initialized to non-undefined value to start with): if (newVal === oldVal || oldVal === undefined) return;